# Efficient way to move list items at the end of the list according to specific criteria

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, performance, list, sorting

Having a `List<Office>` where Office is a class, I have to sort its entries by country (where country is a property of class Office).

Some offices have no country set and therefore will be displayed at the top of the list. In this case I have to put them at the bottom of the list since considered "less relevant".

```
switch (sortOptions.SortField)

...  

case OfficeSortField.Country:

var noCountryList = officesList.Where(a => string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.CountryText)).ToList();
officesList.RemoveAll(a => string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.CountryText));

officesList= sortOptions.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending
                                      ? officesList.OrderBy(o => o.CountryText).ToList()
                                      : officesList.OrderByDescending(o => o.CountryText).ToList();

officesList.AddRange(noCountryAssoList);
break;
```

Under perfomance perspective, is there a better way to proceed?

Comment: Which language? Most have a `sort` function which you can use to sort by a custom criteria.

Comment: All similar and good answers. In my case,the movement at the end of the list is needed only in a very specific case (this is only one among many sort possibilities of a Telerick Grid). 
I will post my code for completeness, though not performant or elegant as the one suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way for this is to implement a [comparer](http://www.google.tn/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCMQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx&ei=zBtcUJ2aAojCswae84CADA&usg=AFQjCNEwmi_81-El8gB-IfLsrU4dIJBFIA&sig2=39RNsnqIw4aR1iLMEG7f-Q):

```
class OfficeComparer:IComparer<Office>
{
        int IComparer.Compare(Office a, Office b)
        {
               if ( a.Office.Country != null && b.Office.Country != null) 
                       return a.Office.Country.CompareTo(b.Office.Country);
               if ( a.Office.Country == null && b.Office.Country != null) return -1;
               if ( a.Office.Country != null && b.Office.Country == null) return 1;  
               return 0; // if both have no country, return equal or whatever other criteria comparaison

        }
}
```

in your comparer, you just give a low priority to office without a country, and then just call the sort method:

```
List<Office> lst = FillList();

lst.sort(new OfficeComparer());
```

Answer (score 2):

The performance differences you would notice for these sort of things will be so minor its not worth worrying about. If you are not already doing so I would use Linq to carry out the logic to just sort by whatever you want, so you don't have to do any removing/inserting.

Then if you want to improve performance further look at using Plinq to spread the logic over multiple cores.

Comment: In my case there won't be probably so many elements to require the need of Plinq. However good point to think about in a future case +1!

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to sort using a custom function.

You can do it as a delegate:

```
list.Sort((first, second) =>
      {
         // Your code to compare first and second items
         // return 0 if equal, -1 or +1 for other cases
      });
```

You could do all your process in one pass, you don't need to extract offices without countries.

Answer (score 2):

Sure there is. Try this one:

```
List<Office> list = new List<Office>(...);

list.Sort((x, y) => x.Country == null ? (y.Country == null ? 0 : -1) :
    (y.Country == null ? 1 : Comparer<Office>.Default.Compare(x, y))
```

Or, you should better implement the comparer (if you are going to reuse the sorting thing).

```
class OfficeComparer : IComparer<Office>
{
    public int Compare(Office a, Office b)
    {
        return a.Country == null ? (b.Country == null ? 0 : -1) :
            (b.Country == null ? 1 : Comparer<Office>.Default.Compare(a, b))
    }
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
List<Office> list = new List<Office>(...);
list.Sort(new OfficeComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IComparable or ICompare interface and define which object of two object is "greater" than second.

You can find more in this knowledge base article on [How to use the IComparable and IComparer interfaces in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727)

Answer (score 0):

This is most easiest and performance effective, I retrieve all physics book, in that I want to push the category "other" to be listed in end of the list.

```
List<Books> controlGroupDetails = controlDetails.Where(s => s.Title == "Physics").ToList();
var otherPhysics = controlDetails.Where(s => s.Title == "Physics" && s.Name == "Other").SingleOrDefault();
controlGroupDetails.Remove(otherPhysics);
controlGroupDetails.Insert(controlGroupDetails.Count(), otherPhysics);
```

Answer (score -1):

In Java, you can implement `Comparable<T>` interface and then sort the list by invoking `java.util.Collections.sort(List<T> list)`.

See details:

```
public class Office implements Comparable<Office> {
  private String country;
  public int compareTo(Office off) {
    if (this.country == null)
      return -1;
    else if (off.country == null)
      return 1;
    else
      return this.country.compareTo(off.country);
  }
}
```

Sort the list:

```
java.util.Collections.sort(yourOfficeList);
```

Comment: OK, ignore my post. But hope there is similar thing in C#.

Comment: Sure it is. Java is like C# :)

Comment: You compare only first to second whereas you should do both ways.

Comment: @AgentFire: no need to do that in Java, this is just the same as the one in C#, see lcfseth's answer.